# 1:n relationship and sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, relation

I have two tables 
entries(id,name,desc,cat_id)
and
categories(id,name,parent)

entries.cat_id and categories.id are FK and between entries and categories there is a 1:n relationship. So how to get distinct cat_id from entries and its name in categories.
I tried with

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  entries.cat_id
FROM entries
JOIN categories ON categories.id = entries.cat_id
```

but I get only cat_id as result but I want categories name also. Where is my mistake? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
cat_id, categories.name
FROM entries JOIN categories ON categories.id = entries.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the column you want to your select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT entries.cat_id
                categories.name
FROM            entries    
JOIN            categories ON categories.id = entries.cat_id
```

Comment: I thought it was allowed only to add columns from `entries` in that part of the sql. Thank you :)